# Filter SQL query by dropdown

Tags: php, sql

I want to filter my SQL. I made a function for that, the filter is only with dropdowns.

But this function is not working very well.

This is my function which is called on the `List.php`:

```
function getFilterList ($Category, $Price, $Language) {
    $servername = "localhost";
    $username_connect = "root";
    $password_connect = "";
    $dbname = "Product";
    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username_connect, $password_connect, $dbname);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysqli_error($link) );
    }

    if($Category=="0") {
        $filtercategory= "Hardware' OR Category='Software' OR Category='Games' OR Category='Sport' OR Category='Other";
    } else if($Category=="1") {
        $filtercategory="Hardware";
    } else if($Category=="2") {
        $filtercategory="Software";
    } else if($Category=="3") {
        $filtercategory="Games";
    } else if($Category=="4") {
        $filtercategory="Sport";    
    } else if($Category=="5") {
        $filtercategory="Other";    
    }

    if($Price=="0"){
        $filterprice= "0' OR Price='5' OR Price='10' OR Price='15' OR Game='20' OR Price='30";
    } else if($Price=="1") {
        $filterprice="5";
    } else if($Price=="2") {
        $filterprice="10";
    } else if($Price=="3") {
        $filterprice="15";
    } else if($Price=="4") {
        $filterprice="20";
    } else if($Price=="5") {
        $filterprice="30";
    }

    if ($Language=="0") {
        $filterlanguage= "German' OR Language='Englisch' OR Language='France' OR Language='Spanish";
    } else if ($Language=="1") {
        $filterlanguage="German";
    } else if ($Language=="2") {
        $filterlanguage="Englisch";
    } else if ($Language=="3") {
        $filterlanguage="France";
    } else if ($Language=="4") {
        $filterlanguage="Spanish";
    }

    $link = mysqli_connect($servername, $username_connect, $password_connect, $dbname);
    if (!$link) {
        die('Verbindung nicht möglich : ' . mysqli_error($link) );
    }

    $get_product = "SELECT * FROM products WHERE (ShortDescription!='' AND Category='$filtercategory' AND Price='$filterprice' AND Language='$filterlanguage') order by ID DESC";

    $run_product = mysqli_query($link, $get_product);
    while($row_product = mysqli_fetch_array($run_product)) {
        $product_id = $row_product["ID"];
        $ProuductShortDescription = $row_product["ShortDescription"];
        echo "
            <div id='Single_Product'>
                <a href='details.php?ID=$product_id' class='ui-btn' id='ProductButton'>$ProductShortDescription</a>
            </div>";
    }
}
```

This is my `Filter.php`:

```
<form action="List.php" method="post">
    <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true">
        <select name="FilterselectCategory" id="FilterselectCategory">
            <option value="0">Category</option>
            <option value="1">Hardware</option>
            <option value="2">Software</option>
            <option value="3">Games</option>
            <option value="3">Sport</option>
            <option value="4">Other</option>
        </select>

        <select name="FilterselectPrice" id="FilterselectPrice">
            <option value="0">Price</option>
            <option value="1">0</option>
            <option value="2">5</option>
            <option value="3">10</option>
            <option value="4">15</option>
            <option value="5">20</option>
            <option value="6">30</option>
        </select>

        <select name="FilterselectLanguage" id="FilterselectLanguage">
             <option value="0">Language</option>
            <option value="1">Englisch</option>
            <option value="2">German</option>
            <option value="3">France</option>
            <option value="4">Spanish</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>

    <input type="submit" id="FilterButton" name="FilterButton" value="Filter">
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: You're very trusting.  I'm told the most common site hack is the MYSQL injection attack.  You need to look at mysqli_prepare
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php